# Cannot reference classes from interfaces after upgrading to VS2017

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, typescript-typings, typescript2.2

I get `Cannot find name 'x'` in typescript interface files when they reference classes in the same module, but are in a different file.

Example:

**MyClass.ts**

```
module MyModule
{
    export class MyClass
    {
        constructor()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**MyInterface.d.ts**

```
declare module MyModule
{
    export interface MyInterface
    {
        Test: MyClass;
    }
}
```

This shows `Cannot find name 'MyClass'`, however it is highlighted blue as if it knows what it is. VS successfully builds, however the errors are shown in the error window. This used to be fine before upgrading from VS2015. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is expected behavior. Your interface is defined in a definition file (`d.ts`) which cannot contain references to actual code file (non definition files / `.ts`).

Comment: @Igor I'm not sure why that is not allowed? To get this to stop erroring would I have to change the interface to a class?

Comment: No, that would also not work as a `d.ts` file cannot contain classes or any implementations for that matter. The `d` stands for definition, think of this as contracts with no implementation at all. The primary intent of these files was to be able to define interfaces for javascript (non-typescript) files.